# Tabularx and itemize missing item

Tags: tables, tabularx, itemize, booktabs

when I  do this :

```
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{5cm}|p{5cm}|} 
\toprule
\textbf{KPI} & \textbf{Description} \endhead 
\toprule
\rowcolor{darkgrey} \textbf{The percentage of health and safety trained managers and employees in the workplace}  & \begin{itemize}
\item The percentage of trained managers for occupational health and safety in the institute.
\item The percentage of trained employees for occupational health and safety in the institute.
\end{itemize}  \\ 
\midrule
 \textbf{Frequency of health and safety committee meetings}  & \begin{itemize}\item The number of health and safety committee short meetings per month.
 \item The number of health and safety committee general meetings per year. 
\end{itemize} \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor{darkgrey} \textbf{Frequency of inspection} & \begin{itemize}

\item Number of inspections per year.
\item Frequency of observation of unsafe behaviors.
 \end{itemize} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Frequency of auditing} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Number of health and safety management system auditing per year.
\end{itemize}   \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor{darkgrey}  \textbf{Health and safety management team members commitments}  & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Number of deliverables per team member. 
\item Number of participants in the committee meetings.
\end{itemize}   \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Number of precaution procedures} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Frequency of early warnings.
\item Number of first aid kits and fire drills.
\item Number of trained employees for first aid kits and fire drills.
\end{itemize}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
```

I get this

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{tabularx}
```

how can I solve this ?  I'm using

```
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx}
```

Comment: You might want to have a look at the enumitem package. With it you can get rid of the spaces between the items and top align the list with the contents of the first column.

Comment: You might also want to keep in mind that the horizontal lines from the booktabs package are incompatible with vertical lines. (see the small gaps in the vertical lines at the intersections. )

Comment: For alternated row colors, you might want to use the rowcolors instead of the rowcolor command.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest a slightly different layout of your tabular. As you see from your example, the text in first and second *column* is not on the same baseline, which is considered as bad typography. In addition, all the vertical and horizontal rules are unnecessary when you use shading. Also, you get white lines scattered around because neither `\rowcolor` and `booktabs`-rules, nor `booktabs`-rules and vertical rules, are compatible. If your tabular is part of a document, the text will not line up on the left and right margin, not very nice.

> The code for cancelling space above list-items is adapted from David Carlisle code in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400920/9632).

Here is my suggestion, and if you are interested, I can explain the different steps.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array,booktabs}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.15}
\usepackage{lmodern, microtype}

\newcolumntype{P}{p{\dimexpr(0.5\linewidth-1em-2\tabcolsep)}}
\newcolumntype{Z}{p{\dimexpr(2em-2\tabcolsep)}}
\newcommand{\listbox}[1]{\parbox[t]{\dimexpr(\linewidth-\tabcolsep)}{\mbox{}\vspace{-\normalbaselineskip\relax}\begin{itemize}[nosep, leftmargin=1em,]#1\end{itemize}}}

\newcommand{\rowspace}{\addlinespace[0.5\normalbaselineskip]}

\setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{3pt}

%%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
%\usepackage{showframe}
%\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
%\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%%---------------------------------------------------------------%

\begin{document}

\setlength{\tabcolsep}{1pt}
\noindent\begin{tabular}{>{\bfseries}PZP} 

KPI && \textbf{Description} \\
\addlinespace[0.25\normalbaselineskip]\toprule
\arrayrulecolor{darkgrey}\hline
\rowcolor{darkgrey}
The percentage of health and safety trained managers and employees in the workplace  & &
\listbox{\item The percentage of trained managers for occupational health and safety in the institute
\item The percentage of trained employees for occupational health and safety in the institute} \par\\
\rowspace
 Frequency o health and safety committee meetings  &&
 \listbox{\item The number of health and safety committee short meetings per month
 \item The number of health and safety committee general meetings per year} \par\\ 

\arrayrulecolor{darkgrey}\hline
\rowcolor{darkgrey}Frequency of inspection & &
\listbox{\item Number of inspections per year
\item Frequency of observation of unsafe behaviors} \par\\
\arrayrulecolor{darkgrey}\hline
\rowspace
Frequency of auditing & &
\listbox{\item Number of health and safety management system auditing per year}   \par\\ 

\arrayrulecolor{darkgrey}\hline
\rowcolor{darkgrey}Health and safety management team members commitments  & &
\listbox{\item Number of deliverables per team member 
\item Number of participants in the committee meetings}   \par\\ 
\arrayrulecolor{darkgrey}\hline
\rowspace
Number of precaution procedures & &
\listbox{\item Frequency of early warnings
\item Number of first aid kits and fire drills
\item Number of trained employees for first aid kits and fire drills} \par\\
\bottomrule[2pt]
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I guessing you mean "first and second *columns* not rows ...

Comment: @Zarko Thank you, Zarko. As a payback, I will give you the link to David Carlisle brilliant solution for cancelling the irritating space above lists. I saw it today, but have needed it for years. [Here it is.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/400920/9632)

Comment: Thank you for the link ... i would like to show my solution which i have stored on my home server, but unfortunately temporally  it is down and I'm not able to recover it remotely :-( (for now only+1 for your answer)

Answer (score 2):

One more possible solution ...

- with use of `enumitem` and `etoolbox` package lists `itemize` inside tables are accommodate to use in tables
- for horizontal rules in table are used lines defined in the `boldline` package
- for column with lists is define new column type `I` (see MWE below)

**Edit:**

- more top vertical spaces in cells are achieved by use of the `cellspace` package and bottom with settings of `itemize` in table
- removed are not used code fragments and corrected column type definitions

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{boldline,
            cellspace,
            tabularx}
\setlength\cellspacetoplimit{5pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AtBeginEnvironment{table}{%
    \setlist[itemize]{nosep,     % <-- new list setup
                      leftmargin=*,
                      label=\textbullet,%% <===
                      after=\vspace{-0.8\baselineskip} %% <===
                      }
                           }% end of AtBeginEnvironment
\newcolumntype{I}{>{\csname @minipagetrue\endcsname%
                  \RaggedRight\itemize}X<{\enditemize}
                    }

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[ht]
    \rowcolors{1}{white}{gray!15}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{>{\bfseries\RaggedRight}S{p{48mm}} I}%% <===
    \hlineB{2}
KPI & \multicolumn{1}{>{\bfseries}l}{Description} \\
    \hlineB{1.5}
The percentage of health and safety trained managers and employees in the workplace 
    &    \item  The percentage of trained managers for occupational health and safety in the institute.
         \item  The percentage of trained employees for occupational health and safety in the institute.
         \\
Frequency of health and safety committee meetings
    &   \item The number of health and safety committee short meetings per month.
        \item The number of health and safety committee general meetings per year.
        \\
Frequency of inspection 
    &   \item Number of inspections per year.
        \item Frequency of observation of unsafe behaviors.
        \\
Frequency of auditing
    &   \item Number of health and safety management system auditing per year.
        \\
Health and safety management team members commitments 
    &   \item Number of deliverables per team member.
        \item Number of participants in the committee meetings.
        \\
Number of precaution procedures  
    &   \item Frequency of early warnings.
        \item Number of first aid kits and fire drills.
        \item Number of trained employees for first aid kits and fire drills.   
        \\
    \hlineB{2}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

Result is:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

By changing your `\endhead` to `\\` and adding the packages needed (plus changing a column type to `X` in order to let tabularx "work") this error is gone:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx,booktabs,colortbl}
%\usepackage{xcolor}
\definecolor{darkgrey}{cmyk}{0,0,0,.4}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|p{5cm}|X|} 
\toprule
\textbf{KPI} & \textbf{Description} \\
\toprule
\rowcolor{darkgrey} \textbf{The percentage of health and safety trained managers and employees in the workplace}  & \begin{itemize}
\item The percentage of trained managers for occupational health and safety in the institute.
\item The percentage of trained employees for occupational health and safety in the institute.
\end{itemize}  \\ 
\midrule
 \textbf{Frequency of health and safety committee meetings}  & \begin{itemize}\item The number of health and safety committee short meetings per month.
 \item The number of health and safety committee general meetings per year. 
\end{itemize} \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor{darkgrey} \textbf{Frequency of inspection} & \begin{itemize}

\item Number of inspections per year.
\item Frequency of observation of unsafe behaviors.
 \end{itemize} \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Frequency of auditing} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Number of health and safety management system auditing per year.
\end{itemize}   \\ 
\midrule
\rowcolor{darkgrey}  \textbf{Health and safety management team members commitments}  & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Number of deliverables per team member. 
\item Number of participants in the committee meetings.
\end{itemize}   \\ 
\midrule
\textbf{Number of precaution procedures} & 
\begin{itemize}
\item Frequency of early warnings.
\item Number of first aid kits and fire drills.
\item Number of trained employees for first aid kits and fire drills.
\end{itemize}  \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help! However I'm still getting errors that I do not understand, after editing this. 
`! LaTeX Error: \caption outside float.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... \end{tabularx}`
and 
`! Undefined control sequence.\caption ... \endcsname \fi \fi \@dblarg {\@tempf\@captype } \end{tabularx}`
you helped me out already a lot with eliminating most of the errors!

Comment: @Felix ... This is probably a new problem that doesn't respond to your MWE here ... Please consider opening a new issue.