# Itemize within tabularx ==> missing item

Tags: luatex

I don't understand why LuaLatex complains about missing items. I tried the following code. Using the [mentioned](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/503541/48642) packages `enumitem` and `etoolbox` didn't help.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic,english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{enumerate} 
\usepackage{ltablex} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\begin{document}
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{ X }
  \begin{itemize}
    \item 33
    \item my first item
  \end{itemize}
 \end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

I tried to condense my sample until this error appears. Help would be appreciated to figure out what is wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a mis-feature in the `ltablex` package that it converts `X` columns to `l` so not allowing display items like lists.

Use

```
\usepackage{ltablex} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\keepXColumns
```

To stop it doing that.

Comment: Thx - this helped.

Comment: probably better to use the xltabular package and the xltabular environment for long tabulars instead, it reinstates tabularx.

Comment: I have the followup problem: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571424/48642. @UlrikeFischer: Unfortunately I cannot test right away `xltabular`. But would this solve the problems?

Comment: well you can test if it compiles if you don't use ltablex but the original tabularx. If it does it will work with xltabular too, as these package doesn't change tabularx.