# Rowcolor in xltabular and whitespace

Tags: tables

I followed several suggestions to get rid of the additional whitespace when adding a `hrule` between table rows. I have the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper, margin=2.5cm]{geometry} 
\usepackage[shorthands=off,bidi=basic,english, ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color

%------regular rule -------
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tablehline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother
%-------------------------

\begin{document}
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X  X  X @{}}
\tablehline
\rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9} 
\textbf{Firstname} &  
\textbf{Lastname} &  
\textbf{Age} \\
\tablehline

\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jill &  
Smith &  
50 \\
\tablehline

Eve &  
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jackson &  
94 \\
\tablehline

John1 &  
Doe &  
80 \\
\tablehline

\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

The whole code works quite well up to the point when introducing `@{}` in the table. Obviously the ruler is not extended to this area. Is there a way to extend the ruler as well?
[image: Ruler not extending]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to my question is a more less not clearly documented option (lr)

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off, bidi=basic, english, ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep

\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}

\rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
\textbf{Firstname} &
\textbf{Lastname} &
\textbf{Age} \\
\bottomrule(lr)
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jill &
Smith &
50 \\
\midrule(lr)
Eve &
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jackson &
94 \\
\midrule(lr)

John1 &
Doe &
80 \\
\midrule(lr)
\end{xltabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use`\cmidrule` from `booktabs`, which can use a trimming argument, like this:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off, bidi=basic, english, ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color
%------regular rule -------
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\tablehline}{%
    \noalign {\ifnum 0=`}\fi \hrule height 1pt
    \futurelet \reserved@a \@xhline
}
\makeatother
%-------------------------
\begin{document}

{\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep
\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
%\tablehline
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
\textbf{Firstname} &
\textbf{Lastname} &
\textbf{Age} \\
%\tablehline
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jill &
Smith &
50 \\
%\tablehline
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}
Eve &
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jackson &
94 \\
\tablehline

John1 &
Doe &
80 \\
\tablehline
\end{xltabular}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hmmm... this seems to works although not my preferred solution. The major problem with this is that I need to know the amount of column in advance. Since I automatically generate the code this is a non-trivial approach. AND I need to stretch the line anyway over all columns. Isn't there a simpler solution which doesn't require to know the no of columns in advance?

Comment: Unfortunately, among the rules of booktabs, only \cmidrule has the trimming functionality. Maybe patching the code  for `\midrule` might add this functionality. I'll try to see whether it's possible.

Comment: A side note: I didn't test in details. Nevertheless I know I have as well nested tables - which might influence the width of a table. So, my point here is that its not necessarily the `\textwidth` which should be used. Just a side note in case of a fix!

Comment: Could you post an example code? Note nested tabulars are often not necessary, as there are alternative solutions.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/571466/48642 But plz: Don't blame me cuz as mentioned before - they are generated automatically. If the ruler finally doesn't apply for nested I don't care so much. It's just in the case an easy adaption is possible. BTW: In the nested tables `\midrule` works fine.