# Booktabs and multicolumns

Tags: booktabs

I want to exend the line in `xltabular` to cover as well the definitons of `@{}`. For this question I found a [solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572958/48642) with the optional parameter `(lr)` which is more or less documented in the `booktabs` documentation under `Booktabs and longtables`. But somehow the fix doesn't work if the `rule` is followed by a line which spans over the whole table width.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off, bidi=basic, english, ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep
\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
\textbf{Firstname} &
\textbf{Lastname} &
\textbf{Age} \\
\bottomrule(lr)
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jill &
Smith &
50 \\
\midrule(lr)
Eve &
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jackson &
94 \\
\midrule(lr)
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
%   \midrule(lr) %<-------------------------- failure: Misplaced \omit. \end{xltabular} 
    \multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax} X @{}}{
    span over multiple rows with long text to fill in to cover the distance} \\
    column 1 & column2 \\
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
%   \midrule(lr) %<-------------------------- failure: Misplaced \noalign. \end{xltabular} 
    \rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
    \textbf{Firstname} &
    \textbf{Lastname} &
    \textbf{Age} \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

Is there a way to fix both of the errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some minor changes to your document (marked). I hope it helps.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[shorthands=off, bidi=basic, english, ngerman]{babel}%
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\aboverulesep=0pt
\belowrulesep=0pt
\cmidrulekern=-\tabcolsep
\usepackage{xltabular} % for tables with long lines & long tables (over >1 page)
\usepackage{luacolor,lua-ul} %for usage of style attributes - background color

\begin{document}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
\cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3}
\rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
\textbf{Firstname} &
\textbf{Lastname} &
\textbf{Age} \\
\bottomrule(lr)
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jill &
Smith &
50 \\
\midrule(lr)
Eve &
\cellcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}Jackson &
94 \\
\midrule(lr)
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X @{}}
    \cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-2}  %<-------------------------- changed
        \multicolumn{2}{@{}>{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax} X @{}}{
        span over multiple rows with long text to fill in to cover the distance span over multiple rows } \\ %longer text
    column 1 & column2 \\
\end{xltabular}

\begin{xltabular}{\textwidth}{@{} X X X @{}}
   \cmidrule[1pt](lr){1-3} %<--------------------------changed
    \rowcolor[HTML]{b96ad9}
    \textbf{Firstname} &
    \textbf{Lastname} &
    \textbf{Age} \\
\end{xltabular}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Although I would have preferred a different solution I now have used this one. Thx for the effort.